# Abrir url de youtube en App

Tags: android, android-studio

Al hacer click en un enlace de un video de YouTube, por ejemplo desde el navegador o desde una app como whatsapp este abre la aplicación de youtube,
En ese caso si existen mas aplicaciones que pueden "controlar" la url, se activa la siguiente pantalla para poder elegir que aplicación va a iniciar, deseo que mi aplicación pueda aparecer ahí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este caso las aplicación reproducen el video igual como lo haría YouTube.
Entonces supongo que el intent que abre la aplicación, lleva un string, que se debe recuperar,  en ese caso la url del video.
Tengo un webview, necesitaría obtener ese string y cargarlo.

En la configuración de youtube y de las demás app podemos ver que aparecen las url que admiten esas aplicaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las aplicaciones que aparecen en la lista contienen esas url, donde tendría que colocar esas url en mi proyecto.

Encontré un [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177813/android-open-video-with-custom-app), que expone el mismo tema pero no se como implementar la respuesta para lo que necesito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` añade un `Intent-filter` donde definas los dominios que usa la aplicación de Youtube pero para tu aplicación:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtu.be" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.youtube.com" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
       <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" />
  </intent-filter>
```

de esta forma cuando cargues alguno de los dominios se sugerirá tu aplicación también :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo, suponiendo que tu actividad principal es MainActivity :

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtu.be" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="m.youtube.com" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.youtube.com" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Esto es para que la aplicación sea capaz de abrir el enlace ,no? Osea que al tener un enlace de YouTube la aplicación también aparezca como una opción

Comment: Funciono, le agregue
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />, para que funcione con enlaces desde el navegador también.

Comment: @christian. Sirve para cuando se da click en un enlace de youtube, en ese caso ya no abriría youtube directamente, sino que aparecería el cuadro de diálogo de desambiguación , para que el usuario elija la app con que desea abrir el enlace, en mi caso yo tengo un webView, entonces recupero la url, y la cargo con load()

Comment: Es verdad debe llevar también la categoría BROWSABLE ya que es necesaria para cuando se escriba en el navegador el dominio @Redox , actualice la respuesta, saludos.